# Very Slow MYSQL Sub Query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Guys,  im more of a MSSQL guy but im working on some MYSQL right now.

Iv written a simple query, with a subquery and I cant understand for the life of me why its so slow.

This query:

```
   SELECT MAX(timestamp), user, status FROM checkin WHERE room_id = 'Room Name' AND timestamp        > DATE_SUB(Now() ,INTERVAL 4005 SECOND) GROUP BY user
```

Runs in 0.0034 seconds

Yet this relatively similiar query but nested,  takes over 6 seconds ..

```
SELECT user, status FROM checkin
WHERE timestamp IN
(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM checkin WHERE room_id = 'Room Name' AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(Now() ,INTERVAL 4005 SECOND) GROUP BY user)
```

Can anyone please help?  Im stuck.

The table "checkin" only has about 900 rows in it.  only the room_id column is indexed.

Cheers

**EDIT**
Thanks guys .. heres the result of the EXPLAIN

DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  checkin ref room_id room_id 202 const   1104    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Run EXPLAIN on both SELECT statements separately. The GROUP BY maybe using a temporary table.

Comment: posting the output of explain will probably help if my answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into using a `HAVING` clause to achieve the same results. MySQL is notoriously bad at sub-query optimization, try this:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) as ts, user, status 
FROM checkin
WHERE room_id = 'Room Name' 
AND   timestamp > DATE_SUB(Now() ,INTERVAL 4005 SECOND)
GROUP BY user
HAVING timestamp = ts
```

also make sure that there is an index on `timestamp`

Alternatively:

```
SELECT user, status 
FROM checkin
WHERE room_id = 'Room Name' 
AND   timestamp > DATE_SUB(Now() ,INTERVAL 4005 SECOND)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM checkin as newer 
                WHERE newer.timestamp>checkin.timestamp
                AND newer.room_id = 'Room Name'
                AND newer.user = checkin.user)
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: Hmm .. iv tried this query, but it returns nothing ..  if I remove the "HAVING" line, I see the time stamps im after, but the status's are wrong.

Comment: I should mention that multiple records will be returned .. not just 1.  I think the having clause wont work in that case

Comment: So very close!.  I have to add the "timestamp" into the select list, otherwise it tells me It cant find the column.   When i do, it returns zero results.     When I remove the HAVING clause, I can see the right amount of records, with unique "user" column, and the TS column is showing the latest timestamp for each ...  but the "status" column is wrong ... showing an old record..               Its so very close, but just not quite there.  I cant figure out why it returns no records when the HAVING clause is included though

Comment: Your a genius ...  I think that one has done the trick ..  everything looks good to me :) and its quick too..      Was it just the GROUP BY that was taking so long ??

Comment: Spoke too soon ... now iv got multiple user counts coming back ..   ie,  2 records per user  :(

Comment: If you are getting multiple records per user, then you must have people checking in to the same room multiple times with the same timestamp. I've added something to the query that'll disambiguate arbitrarily between those

Answer (score 2):

I think, that you are dealing with dependent subquery. This means, that subquery is not executed once (as you and I would expect), but for every row - it is a known bug of MySQL. If you can, split it into two queries - find out the MAX value first and then do a selection.

Comment: Hmmm .. i think you might be right ...  Do you have any suggestions of the query?

Answer (score 1):

Please run EXPLAIN on both queries. Propably you dont have proper indexes on your columns.

Try that:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT user, status FROM checkin WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM checkin WHERE room_id = 'Room Name' AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(Now() ,INTERVAL 4005 SECOND) GROUP BY user);
```

And:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM checkin WHERE room_id = 'Room Name' AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(Now() ,INTERVAL 4005 SECOND) GROUP BY user
```

Comment: Its come back with    
    2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY checkin ref room_id room_id 202 const 1247 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort